# Toggle Mongo Document Date Property With Single Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Knowing just the `_id` of a document in Mongo is there a straightforward way to write ONE update query to do the following? I think the answer is "no", but I'd like to know about it if there is something that does let this happen.

0. Target a document by `_id` (single document).
1. If the `readAt` field exists on the document, remove it
2. If the `readAt` field does NOT exist on the document, set it to the current time

Essentially, I want to "toggle" the "read" state (using a Date as a flag) of the document without actually first fetching the document.

Currently I'm using something like:

```js
collection.update(
  {_id: notificationDoc._id},
  notificationDoc.readAt
    ? {$unset: {readAt: true}}
    : {$set: {readAt: new Date()}}
)
```

which works fine, but requires I first read in that field. I'm not really worried about race conditions or anything, I'd just prefer to cut out the round trip to the DB.

---

I've thought of a couple of ways to do it with two update queries in serial with distinct conditions, but that doesn't seem like an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your [MongoDB version is >= 4.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) then you can specify aggregate pipeline in you update query.

```
db.collection.update(
{ _id: notificationDoc._id },
[
  {
    $set: {
      readAt: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $lte: [
              "$readAt",
              null
            ]
          },
          "$$NOW",
          "$$REMOVE" //(previously null)
        ]
      }
    },
    
  }
])
```

Above query will set `readtAt` to **null** (or remove it if `$$REMOVE` is provided)  `if it exists` and to **current date time** `if not exist/null`

[You can see how the comparison works](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/)

Comment: Ah, thanks. That actually looks pretty close. The goal would be to $unset it if it existed rather than set it to null. It looks like `$cond` always specifies one of two values from the documentation. Perhaps it is possible to have the second stage in the pipeline be an $unset on the field conditioned on it having a value of null. I may try to track down if that's possible with aggregation pipelines now I see that's possible in 4.2.

Comment: I have updated my answer, thanks to @prasad_ +1 for introducing the `$$REMOVE`

Comment: it will now remove the `readAt` key if it doesn't exist

Comment: After a couple of tests, looks like it works great! Learned something new. Thanks for revisiting it.

Answer (score 1):

The update (toggle) logic can be implemented as follows - I will explain with an example. Consider a collection with two documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "readAt" : "2020-07-01", "fld" : "Y" }
{ "_id" : 2, "fld" : "N" }
```

The following aggregation removes the `readAt`field in the document with `_id: 1` and sets the `readAt: "2020-07-08"` for the document with `_id: 2`.

```
var NEW_VALUE = "2020-07-08";

db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          readAt: { 
              $let: {
                  vars: { readAtExists: { $ifNull: [ "$readAt", null ] } },
                  in: { $cond: [ {$eq: [ "$$readAtExists", null ]}, NEW_VALUE, "$$REMOVE"  ] }
              }
          }
      }
  }
])
```

Based on this aggregation you can update the document in one of the following two ways. The *first option* works with MongoDB versions 4.2 or newer (uses [Update with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline)), and the *second option* works with versions earlier than the 4.2.

**1) Update with Aggregation Pipeline**

```
db.collection.update(
  { _id: 1 },  // { _id: 2 }
  [
    { 
        $set: { 
            readAt: { 
                $let: {
                    vars: { readAtExists: { $ifNull: [ "$readAt", null ] } },
                    in: { $cond: [ {$eq: [ "$$readAtExists", null ]}, NEW_VALUE, "$$REMOVE"  ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  ]
)
```

**2) Aggregate and Update:**

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  {
      $match: { _id: 1 }  // { _id: 2 }
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          readAt: { 
              $let: {
                  vars: { readAtExists: { $ifNull: [ "$readAt", null ] } },
                  in: { $cond: [ {$eq: [ "$$readAtExists", null ]}, NEW_VALUE, "$$REMOVE"  ] }
              }
          }
      }
  }
] ).forEach( doc => db.collection.replaceOne( { _id: doc._id }, doc ) )
```

**NOTES:**
You can use the [NOW](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.NOW) aggregation variable with MongoDB v4.2 for setting the date value in an aggregation.